# When needing to reference an NSString later that was passed to a function in a class, what is the proper way? (iPhone dev)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, nsstring, cocos2d-iphone

In this example:

```
@interface something : something  
{  
    NSString *saveString;  
}  

-(void)saveStringForLater:(NSString*)myString  
{  
    //do stuff with myString  
    ...  

    //then save it for later  
    saveString = myString;  
}  

-(void)someOtherTimeInFuture  
{  
    //do stuff with saveString  
    ...  
}
```

So given the above, my questions are:

1) Is this safe/proper way of doing this?
2) Will I need to worry about releasing saveString?
3) Should I be copying the string instead of just saving the pointer?

Excuse my ignorance as I am fairly new to Obj-C but have a C++ and C# background.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `@properties` are for. They manage getter and setter code for you, so you don't have to think about these questions.

.h

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    NSString *myString;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myString;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation MyClass

@synthesize myString;

-(void)dealloc
{
    [myString release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

With those things in place, you can now talk about `self.myString` and not worry about memory. When you assign to it it'll do a retain. If you assign again, it'll release the first object and retain the new one. And then it'll stick around retained until your viewcontroller unloads.

You can by all means accomplish this same end with an iVar (which is what you're doing in your code sample), but then memory management is yours to handle, and it can be a bit fiddly. Best to use the @property system to create appropriately memory-managing setter code.

Comment: Thank you, this looks like exactly what I needed to know and great example.

Comment: One other question though.  When assigning myString do I need to do:  self.myString = string  or can I just do myString = string?

Comment: The property should be `copy`.  @Michael you should read the Objective-C guide as `self.x = y` and `x = y` are quite different;  which you use varies.

Comment: Thanks, but which Obj-C guide specifically? I have glanced at a number of them.  And are you saying that I should use copy instead of retain on the @property? And if so, why?

Comment: @bbum forgot to reference you in my last comment so you would be notified of my response.

Comment: @Michael - It depends what you want. `copy` will make you a new object with the same content, while `retain` will keep a pointer to the same object. I mostly use `retain` unless I really mean something else.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 optins,

1. Copy - should be using if the string can change or when getting called from a code you have on control of like third party
2. Retain - will increase the reference count to the object and will prevent destruction of it

In both these options you have to release it when you done with it

Last you can define a property with retain,copy attribute - this will let the system worry about managing it and probably the best option in most cases